# Yii2: Separate front and backend in advanced-app doesn't work on XAMPP

Tags: .htaccess, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I simply want to access the backend part via `www.domain.com\admin` and frontend by `www.domain.com`. What I did in my root `.htaccess` is :

```
Options -Indexes
# follow symbolic links
Options FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin/$
RewriteRule ^(admin)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin
RewriteRule ^admin(/.+)?$ /backend/web/$1 [L,PT]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /frontend/web/$1
```

It redirects to the the frontend but doesn't work properly with the backend. Can't realize what is the problem because I am using the same lines of configurations at work and there everything is OK. Can it be because of the `XAMPP`? We work on `Ubuntu` and `Apache` server at my workplace. This is the frontend and backend ( they are similar ) also :

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on


# Make the backend accessible via url: http://site/admin
RewriteRule ^admin$ $admin.php [L]

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php


RewriteRule ^static - [L]
```

*EDIT: I DID IT!*
What I was set in my `httpd-vhost.conf` was :

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName fitness
    DocumentRoot "c:/xampp/htdocs/fitness/frontend/web"
</VirtualHost>
```

And the problem was that I was redirecting my request to the `frontend/web` `htaccess` but what I really needed was the root `.htaccess`. So I had changed the `DocumentRoot` to `c:/xampp/htdocs/fitness`.

Comment: what if you can access the `frontend` and `backend` with `www.domain.com` and `admin.domain.com`

Comment: Yes. I can access it like that but this is not what i want :) But your way below is right also.

Comment: okay, so you want the admin section to be accessible via `/admin` only?

Comment: Yup. But still can't realize what is the problem around my `.htaccess` :/

Comment: I did it mate! Thank you very much for you time. As your answer is also correct and someone can get here and make it by your way, I will mark it in green :) Thank you again!

Comment: That was generous of you, thank you i appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use the following way when setting up a new project when I am working in the office where we have `ubuntu` and it always works perfectly.

Follow these steps below, and create 2 virtual hosts with the name `www.myapp.com` and `admin.myapp.com`

1) Open terminal and type

- `sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/www.myapp.com.conf`.
- `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/www.myapp.com.conf`.

add the following code once the file opens.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName www.myapp.com
       DocumentRoot "/path/to/project/root/frontend/web"

       <Directory "/path/to/project/root/frontend/web">
           # use mod_rewrite for pretty URL support
           RewriteEngine on
           # If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
           # Otherwise forward the request to index.php
           RewriteRule . index.php

           # use index.php as index file
           DirectoryIndex index.php

           # ...other settings...
       </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

2) Close & save the file and then in terminal write

- `sudo a2ensite www.myapp.com.conf`
- open hosts file `sudo nano /etc/hosts` and add in the end on a new line `127.0.0.1  www.myapp.com`.
- Restart apache`sudo service apache2 restart`

3) Repeat the above steps for the `backend` and change the file names and  `ServerName`, `Directory` and `DirectoryRoot` respectively.

4) Just make sure you have a `.htaccess` file in the `frontend/web` and `backend/web` with the following

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

And thats it you wont need any other `.htaccess` file other than these now type in the browser `www.myapp.com` or `admin.myapp.com` and see it working.