# Htaccess redirect to controller action don't work properly

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, yii2

I want to redirect to my contoller - `SiteController.php` and action `actionLanguage`. I think my `htaccess` is OK but can't reach the action. Everything that I am trying to put in the url leads me to `admin/site/index` and not to `admin/site/language` in my particular case. My `.htaccess` :

```
# prevent directory listings
Options -Indexes
# follow symbolic links
Options FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin/gii/?$
RewriteRule . backend/web/index.php?r=gii [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin
RewriteRule ^admin(/.+)?$ /backend/web/$1 [L,PT]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /frontend/web/$1
```

This line `RewriteRule ^admin(/.+)?$ /backend/web/$1 [L,PT]` must execute to `backend/web/site/language` when I type `www.website.com/admin/site/language`right ? Or I am in some mistake? It redirects the request to the `admin/site/index` now. Appreciate every advice! Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**:
Backend `.htaccess`:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

Options FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php

RewriteRule ^static - [L]
```

Comment: where does this `.htaccess` is placed, and do you have a `.htaccess`  file inside both `frontend/web/` and `backend/web/` and what are their contents add them too. and are you having this issue on a local computer or live domain? if you are working locally you might need to add the contents virtual host file related to your app `frontend` and `backend`

Comment: It's placed in the root. Will edit the backend htacces. I'm working on XAMPP at this moment so it is local :) So I have to add these lines to the vhost file also ?

Comment: are you on ubuntu or windows ?

Comment: Windows. But I am not at home now so I can't test this solution :)

Comment: okay take your time no issues will add an answer in the evening

Comment: So I tried to put the lines from the root htaccess in the vhost but nothing happened.

Comment: no, you don't have to do that, what if you can access the `frontend` with `www.mysite.local` and `backend` with `admin.mysite.local` would that be okay?

Comment: and you are using `xampp` on windows ?

Comment: Yes xampp on windows but I have to do it this way - `domain.com/admin` :/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48955171/separate-front-and-backend-in-yii2-advanced-doesnt-work-on-xampp/48956244#48956244