# Yii2: Unable to show image on backend and frontend after URL Rewriting

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have changed the frontend/web and backend/web url and I am uploading files inside uploads folder inside application root e.g. "/yii2app/uploads", but unable to show images.

To change frontend and backend url using htaccess. All links are working fine. Also, I am uploading files inside the root folder. From backend application, I am uploading the images into the root folder, which is fine. But I am unable to view the images.

My Root folder HTACCESS

```
Options -Indexes

IndexIgnore */*

#follow symbolic links
Options FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
#without trailing slash
RewriteRule ^admin(/.+)?$ backend/web/$1 [L,PT]
#with trailing slash
RewriteRule ^admin/(.+)?$ backend/web/$1 [L,PT]
RewriteRule ^(.+)?$ frontend/web/$1
```

Front-End HTACCESS

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /yii2app

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php/controller/action
RewriteRule (?!web\/) index.php/$1
```

Back-End HTACCESS

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /yii2app/admin

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

In both config/main.php, added home and base url,

```
/yii2app - frontend
/yii2app/admin - backend
```

Also, I created alias '@root' in common/config/bootstrap.php

```
Yii::setAlias('@root', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../'));
```

Problem is when I try to load img, it's not showing. I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28493615/how-to-upload-files-in-root-folder-in-yii2-advanced-template) for image uploading inside root folder. 
Please help.

**UPDATE**

Below code I used to view the image inside gridview (from backend), but didn't work

```
[
                'label'=>'Event Image',
                'attribute'=>'image_url',
                'format'=>'html',
                'value'=>function($model){
                    return Html::img(Yii::getAlias('@root')."/uploads/events/".$model->id."/".$model->image_url);
                }
            ],
```

Also, tried from backend app

```
[
                'label'=>'Event Image',
                'attribute'=>'image_url',
                'format'=>'html',
                'value'=>function($model){
                    return Html::img("../../uploads/events/".$model->id."/".$model->image_url, ['width' => '170px']);
                }
            ],
```

Am I making a mistake?

Comment: how are you trying to view the images? add the code where you are providing the path to the image moreover you are uploading on the root and the solution you referred to is using `frontend/web` sa the common folder to upload not the root folder

Comment: Please check the update. I tried calling alias @root inside the src of IMG tag, which didn't work. I am not sure, but as I created the alias in common, I thought it would work. Also you mentioned to upload images inside common, so is it that the common folder is only shared between frontend and backend?

Answer (score 0):

You dont set an alias for the root directory but you should use the symbolic links inside the web directory and view the images.

Create a symlink inside the `web` directory of the `frontend` and `backend`.

### For Frontend

```
ln -s /home/username/html/yii2app/uploads /home/username/html/yii2app/frontend/web
```

### For Backend

```
ln -s /home/username/html/yii2app/uploads /home/username/html/yii2app/backend/web
```

and then just use them like below either on frontend or backend

```
<img src="/uploads/filename.jpg" />
```

### Windows10

For those working on localhost with Widows10 OS, want to take advantage of the symbolic links, can use the `mklink` utility on command prompt, which take the link name as the 1st parameter and the source folder as the 2nd.

```
mklink /D c:\xampp\htdocs\yii2app\frontend\web\uploads c:\xampp\htdocs\yii2app\uploads
```

**Note: `/D` is used for creating symlinks to directories**

Comment: I did think about doing this but I thought I am making some mistake and as I am rewriting the url I am somehow unable to access the images.

Comment: I have a regarding creating symlink. In case of the situation like this (for yii2 app), is it wise to create symlink in production to view uploaded images? Is there any other way around to upload the picture and view in both frontend and backend?

Comment: Update: I tried this solution but it didn't work. I create link and showed it in view like this `[
                'label'=>'Event Image',
                'attribute'=>'image_url',
                'format'=>'html',
                'value'=>function($model){
                    return Html::img("uploads/events/".$model->id."/".$model->image_url, ['width' => '170px']);
                }
            ],`

Comment: use a `/` in start and you dont use a relative path you just use the `/path/to/file` either frontend or backend it is as simple as that i tried on my local system before adding an answer, just remove any extra htaccess and keep the default on only , i didnt used your htaccess configuration to check the images loading or Uploading @Mislam

Comment: I finally found the issue. Look at the url `http://localhost/yii2app/admin/events/uploads/events/2/First%20Event.png`, here it should be `http://localhost/yii2app/admin/uploads/events/2/First%20Event.png`, then it works, but I dont know why events after admin in the url, I might have configured wrong. Thanks anyway help. But 1 question, is there any best practice for removing frontend/web and backend/web with pretty url, I saw some tutorial where they are putting index .php out of web folder. It works well. but other links doesn't work, so need to do htaccess again

Comment: the best approach with the least hastle is to create virtual hosts for the frontend and backend and no need to adding any extra url rules. @Mislam , and you can accept the answer if it helped you solve the problem

Comment: you can follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48955171/yii2-separate-front-and-backend-in-advanced-app-doesnt-work-on-xampp/48956244#48956244) for creating virtual hosts

Comment: I know how to create virtual host but as I am going to deploy this app in shared webserver so I was thinking to change the url that way. Thanks.

Comment: Can you in one thing? whenever I add htaccess codes

Comment: Can you help me in one thing? when I add htaccess codes `Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php` in both frontend and backend and enable pretty url   then I see that the src value is this `http://localhost/yii2app/admin/events/uploads/events/2/First.png` , otherwise  `http://localhost/yii2app/admin/uploads/events/2/First.png`.

Comment: add a separate question